# Не удаётся сгенерировать Java-классы из JSON-данных при помощи jsonschema2pojo

Tags: json, gson

Как распарсить [json c сайта](http://catalog.api.2gis.ru/2.0/region/list?format=json&key=rubnkm7490&fields=items.bounds%2Citems.zoom_level%2Citems.time_zone%2Citems.code%2Citems.flags%2Citems.country_code%2Citems.domain)
Пробовал через `jsonschema2pojo`, не получается вставляю кусок `json`

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "api_version": "2.0.1.6.0",
    "issue_date": "20160515"
  },
  "result": {
    "total": 109,
    "items": [{
      "name": "Dubai. Sharjah. Ajman",
      "flags": {
        "public_transport": true,
        "metro": true,
        "road_network": true,
        "flamp": false
      },
      "domain": "ae",
      "bounds": "POLYGON((54.86679 24.763287,55.680597 24.763287,55.680597 25.51707,54.86679 25.51707,54.86679 24.763287))",
      "zoom_level": {
        "min": 9,
        "max": 18
      },
      "code": "dubai",
      "country_code": "ae",
      "id": "99",
      "type": "region",
      "time_zone": {
        "name": "Asia/Dubai",
        "offset": 240
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Lefkosia",
      "flags": {
        "public_transport": true,
        "metro": false,
        "road_network": true,
        "flamp": false
      }
```

Ставлю галочки Json, `GSON`, `use primative types`, `Use double numbers`, `nclude getters and setters`, `Allow additional properties`.
Получаю ошибку:

> There's a problem: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for
>   OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.StringReader@30a7202; line: 31, column:
>   5]) (line 38, column 923)

Answer (score 1):

Из JSON нельзя взять произвольное начало и ожидать, что оно окажется корректным JSON. [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ругается на некорректный JSON, который вы пытаетесь ему скормить. Как минимум, требуется, чтобы баланс скобок (и фигурных, и квадратных) сошёлся - если список где-то начинается с помощью `[`, то он должен где-то закончиться при помощи `]` (запятая разделяет элементы списка), аналогично с объектами: начинаются с `{`, заканчиваются на `}`, свойства разделяются запятыми, имя свойства от значения - двоеточием.

Рекомендую немного почитать про то, [что такое JSON](http://webnotes.by/docs/jquery-javascript/json-v-javascript), наверняка после этого станет понятнее, почему то, что вы пытаетесь вставить, некорректно.

Я бы порекомендовал обрезать JSON лишь после полного описания какой-то страны страны и сохранить все закрывающие скобки, например:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "api_version": "2.0.1.6.0",
    "issue_date": "20160515"
  },
  "result": {
    "total": 109,
    "items": [{
      "name": "Dubai. Sharjah. Ajman",
      "flags": {
        "public_transport": true,
        "metro": true,
        "road_network": true,
        "flamp": false
      },
      "domain": "ae",
      "bounds": "POLYGON((54.86679 24.763287,55.680597 24.763287,55.680597 25.51707,54.86679 25.51707,54.86679 24.763287))",
      "zoom_level": {
        "min": 9,
        "max": 18
      },
      "code": "dubai",
      "country_code": "ae",
      "id": "99",
      "type": "region",
      "time_zone": {
        "name": "Asia/Dubai",
        "offset": 240
      }
    }]
  }
}
```